# gtest-internal.h is not getting gtest-port.h's StripTrailingSpaces method despite having included it

Tags: c++, homebrew, googletest, ros, googlemock

I am using Mac OS X High Sierra and have installed gtest with Homebrew. (Homebrew has gtest only supported up to 1.7.0, while the latest available version of gtest is 1.8.1.) I also tried uninstalling 1.7.0 and building 1.8.1 from source. However, 1.8.1 seems to also have its own errors.

I am building a ros project involving GTest. However, if I try to compile it with `#include "gtest/gtest.h"`, then problems happen.

I get errors such as the following:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest.h:62:
/usr/local/include/gtest/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:643:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'StripTrailingSpaces'
        StripTrailingSpaces(GetPrefixUntilComma(test_names)).c_str(),
```

Many more errors omitted for brevity ([link to the complete compilation error output](https://pastebin.com/Fx6Myuaj)).
This implies that `gtest-internal.h` is not getting the `StripTrailingSpaces` method from `gtest-port.h`, which is quite odd since `gtest-internal.h` has `#include "gtest/internal/gtest-port.h"` near the top of the file.

**Update:**
Attempting to build & install gtest directly from githup also results in many errors ([link to the complete compilation error output](https://pastebin.com/0007hh4L)).

Comment: You seem to have quite a few other errors too: `gmock-generated-internal-utils.h:93:22: error: no member named 'std' in namespace 'testing'; did you mean simply 'std'?` - have you looked into those (as one broken definition often confuses the compiler, leading to even more compilation errors)

Comment: @CharonX I fixed those kinds of errors and updated the post accordingly. See the new pastebin link.

Comment: Fixed those errors as in "edited the gtest files" or as in "added the missing include directory/define"?

Comment: @CharonX Added the missing include/defines, which I suppose is "editing the gtest files" in a way

Comment: Hmmmm... gtest *should* work "out of the box" without needing to edit any souce file - it does a lot of macro-magic during compilation to support all different kinds of environments (e.g. #if defined(__BORLANDC__) and all that). My gut feeling is that your build environment may be not 100% right (maybe does not set all the correct defines) if you need to edit-in additional includes to get it to work (it should suffice to hand the defines and include paths to the compiler, the lib-paths to the linker). Having to edit the .h/.cc files might be a sign that there is a deeper issue

Comment: @CharonX To add more context, I am using Mac OS X High Sierra and have installed gtest with homebrew. Homebrew has gtest supported up to 1.7.0 but the latest available is 1.8.1. I have also tried uninstalling 1.7.0 and tried building 1.8.1 from source. However, 1.8.1 seems to also have its own errors.

Comment: This is rather important information - please edit your question to include that. (And I'm unfortunately out of ideas, honestly)